# Vbscript to open internet explorer application and get a response text

Tags: vbscript

I want to open an Internet Explorer page using vbscript, currently my script is as follows

```
Dim IE
Dim MyDocument
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = 0
IE.navigate "https://google.com"
```

This works fine. The problem is that  I need to get the response of my webpage (google.com) i.e its contents in string format

I know it will be mostly gibberish but I require it for what I am working on

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're almost there already. You just need to wait until the page has finished loading

```
While IE.ReadyState <> 4 : WScript.Sleep 100 : Wend
```

then you can access the page text like this:

```
WScript.Echo IE.document.body.innerText
```

or the page HTML like this:

```
WScript.Echo IE.document.body.innerHTML
```